# Regex to replace spaces and brackets with underscore

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have some strings in the following formats:

```
this is a string
This is a string
This is a (string)
This is a  string
```

and i want a regex convert it to the following:

```
this_is_a_string
```

with no leading

I have the following using preg_replace which is getting me almost all of the way:

```
preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z]+/', '_', $string)
```

However, it converts the last `)` to an underscore which is not acceptable for my uses.  I could easily trim that off in a separate function but im wondering if its possible to do with a single regex?

Comment: It looks like you might be wanting to make a URL slug.  If so, I bet that if you search for "regex to build a URL slug" you could find your answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
$result = preg_replace('~[^A-Z]+([A-Z]+)(?:[^A-Z]+$)?~i', '_$1', $string);
```

Comment: +1 just make it: `strtolower(preg_replace('~[^A-Z]+([A-Z]+)(?:[^A-Z]+$)?~i', '_$1', $string));`

Answer (score 1):

```
$result = preg_replace('~([^a-zA-Z\n\r()]+)~', '_', $string);
```

Try it [HERE](http://regex101.com/r/bF1kQ9)

Be sure tehre's no trailing or leading spaces in your string or it will be replaced too... Use `trim($string)` to remove it

Comment: Actually, I deleted my answer. I was told that I wasn't covering most of the OP's issues. `preg_replace` is the best method to use. Thanks for the mention though, cheers.

Comment: @Fred-ii-, Ow, I didnt really checked your code, but the idea wasnt bad xD

Comment: True, however it did not address the parentheses aspect.

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions are a great tool, but there are some things they're not well suited for. Converting the case of characters is one thing regular expressions alone can't do. You could use the [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) function to transform the matched text to lowercase, but this is actually pretty straight forward to accomplish by simply changing your logic around a bit.

Perhaps something like this instead:

```
$string = 'This is a (string)';
preg_match_all("/[a-zA-Z]+/", $string, $matches);
$string = strtolower(implode('_', $matches[0])); // this_is_a_string
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out to me earlier, I deleted my answer. Yours is obviously the correct method.

Comment: more practical if replace pattern with `\w+`

Comment: @revo yes I considered that (in fact that's how I wrote it originally), but I suspect OP is trying to make a slug for a URL that's written in Latin letters only.

Comment: But I saw formats are limited to 4 numbers & I'm in love with best shortest ways.